# How can I add a footer to a flex-container?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm trying to add a bootstrap footer to my project. It works well on the big screen but when you start scaling down the screen, the footer is placed in the middle of the page instead of the bottom. What am I doing wrong?

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bigcontainer">
  <div class="box1">
    <h3>RENOVATIONS</h3>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p>
      At <em>Razca Designs</em>, we specialize in interior renovation design, from small kitchen updates to complete home remodels. We have a wealth of experience and expertise in creating personalized spaces that reflect our clients’ unique styles and
      personalities.
    </p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p>
      Our team will work closely with you every step of the way to bring your project to completion. We take the time to fully understand the specific challenges and pain points of each client in their current home, and use this information to design a tailor-made
      solution that addresses each individual need. Our approach is to provide you with a beautiful and functional home that you’ll love spending time in
    </p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <b><em>Our passion is creating personalized, welcoming spaces that are tailored to you and your family. With Razca Designs, you can trust us to transform your home into a space that exceeds your expectations</em></b>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <img src="textimages/reno10.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
  </div>
  <div class="box3">
    <img src="textimages/renov-3.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
    <img src="textimages/ren101.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    <h3>RENOVATIONS</h3>
    <p><br /></p>
    <ul class="ab">
      <li>
        Reviewing permits or managing permit applications if necessary
      </li>
      <li>reate the neceesary drawings, including:</li>
      <p>Existing and demolition plans</p>
      <p>Proposed plans</p>
      <p>Construction plans</p>
      <p>Electrical plans.</p>
      <p>Furniture Plans</p>
      <li>
        Providing materials and finishes according to your design palette
      </li>
      <li>Design of custom furniture</li>
      <li>Requesting quotes; ordering and coordinating deliveries</li>
      <li>Dealing contractors and craftsmen</li>
      <li>Dealing with suppliers and overseeing quality control</li>
      <li>
        Final design steps, like finishes and confirming forniture and cabinetery.
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="text-center text-lg-start bg-white text-muted">
  <!-- Section: Social media -->
  <section class="d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-lg-between p-4 border-bottom">
    <!-- Left -->
    <div class="me-5 d-none d-lg-block">
      <span>Get connected with us on social networks:</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Left -->

    <!-- Right -->
    <div>
      <a href="" class="me-4 link-secondary">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="me-4 link-secondary">
        <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="me-4 link-secondary">
        <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="me-4 link-secondary">
        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="me-4 link-secondary">
        <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="me-4 link-secondary">
        <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Right -->
  </section>
  <!-- Section: Social media -->

  <!-- Section: Links  -->
  <section class="">
    <div class="container text-center text-md-start mt-5">
      <!-- Grid row -->
      <div class="row mt-3">
        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mx-auto mb-4">
          <!-- Content -->
          <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-4">
            <i class="fas fa-gem me-3 text-secondary"></i>Company name
          </h6>
          <p>
            Here you can use rows and columns to organize your footer content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </p>
        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 mx-auto mb-4">
          <!-- Links -->
          <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-4">Products</h6>
          <p>
            <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Angular</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a href="#!" class="text-reset">React</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Vue</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Laravel</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 mx-auto mb-4">
          <!-- Links -->
          <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-4">Useful links</h6>
          <p>
            <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Pricing</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Settings</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Orders</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a href="#!" class="text-reset">Help</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mx-auto mb-md-0 mb-4">
          <!-- Links -->
          <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-4">Contact</h6>
          <p>
            <i class="fas fa-home me-3 text-secondary"></i> New York, NY 10012, US
          </p>
          <p>
            <i class="fas fa-envelope me-3 text-secondary"></i> info@example.com
          </p>
          <p>
            <i class="fas fa-phone me-3 text-secondary"></i> + 01 234 567 88
          </p>
          <p>
            <i class="fas fa-print me-3 text-secondary"></i> + 01 234 567 89
          </p>
        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->
      </div>
      <!-- Grid row -->
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Section: Links  -->

  <!-- Copyright -->
  <div class="text-center p-4" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025)">
    © 2021 Copyright:
    <a class="text-reset fw-bold" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/">MDBootstrap.com</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Copyright -->
</footer>
<!-- Footer -->
<!-- Carousel wrapper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Here is my screen shot
[image: big screen]
[image: smaller screen]

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for `<img>` and any other tag

Comment: Is this occurring in a certain browser? 
Tested it in Firefox DE and page works as intended. 
Images even stay in correct locale with no footer text override up high (as shown in image). 
At 768px width the footer auto changes to vertical centered at stays at page bottom (as bootstrap intends). 
Usually @media is used for an DIV id or class....perhaps in your test environment that is effecting the results?

Answer (score 0):

> I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong

```
.bigcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 98vw;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: "sans";
  margin-left: 150px;
}
.bigcontainer::after {
  width: 98vw;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  right: 0;
}

.bigcontainer > div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 18px;
}

.box1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box3 {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.box3 img {
  width: 45%;
  height: 30rem;
}
.box2 img {
  width: 70%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 908px) {
  .bigcontainer > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: max-content;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  .bigcontainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 98vw;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 20px;
    font-family: "sans";
    padding: 15;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 150px;
  }
  .text-container {
    width: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
  }
  .testing {
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .box2 {
    order: 4;
  }
  .box2 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .box3 {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .box3 img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .box2 img {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .bigcontainer::after {
    display: none;
  }
}
.box1 {
  font-family: "sans";
  line-height: 150%;
}
.box4 {
  font-family: "sans";
  line-height: 150%;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.box4 h3 {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.imge-4 {
  width: 100px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0; /* remove the gap so it doesn't close */
}
.text-container {
  width: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}
.testing {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .bigcontainer > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: max-content;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  .bigcontainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 98vw;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 20px;
    font-family: "sans";
    padding: 15;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 150px;
  }
  .testing {
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .text-container {
    width: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
  }

  .box2 {
    order: 4;
  }
  .box2 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .box3 {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .box3 img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .box2 img {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .bigcontainer::after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```